# How to select all radio buttons and exclude one jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have the following code to check if the radio buttons are checked with value true to show a row named `FollowUp`.

```
showHideFollowup: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("input[type='radio'][name='" + e.target.name + "']:checked").val() == "true") {
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup").show();
        }
        else {
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup").hide();
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup input").val(null);
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup textarea").val(null);
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup input[type='radio']").prop("checked", null);
        }
    },
```

I would like to show FollowUp section for all the radio buttons value true except one. After modifying it as follows is not showing followUp section for any radio button because it is checking for rbThisIsNotWorking to be false. How can I achieve what I am looking for?

```
if (($("input[type='radio'][name='" + e.target.name + "']:checked").val() == "true" && $('input:radio[name="#rbThisIsNotWorking"]:checked').val() == "false")) {
            $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup").show();
        }
```

Comment: Use `.val('');` instead of `.val(null);` to reset the element value

Comment: that did not work @Tushar

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after ism to check whether the `rbThisIsNotWorking` element is not checked

```
if ($("input:not(#rbThisIsNotWorking)[type='radio'][name='" + e.target.name + "']").is(':checked')) {
    $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup").show();
} else {
    $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup").hide();
    $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup input").val(null);
    $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup textarea").val(null);
    $(".questionRow" + e.target.name + "Followup input[type='radio']").prop("checked", null);
}
```